# change navigation bar title font - swift

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar

I have a title in my navigation bar and a i want to change it to custom font. I've found this line of code, but it's for when you have a navigation controller.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "LeagueGothic-Regular", size: 16.0)!, 
                                                             NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()]
```

But i don't have any navigation controller. I added navigation bar manually to my view.

[image]

[image]

how can i change comment font?

Comment: Call `titleTextAttributes` on the reference to the navigation bar.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Try this:

**Objective-C**

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:attrsDictionary];
```

**Swift 3**

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "CaviarDreams", size: 20)!]
```

**Swift 4**

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "CaviarDreams", size: 20)!]
```

Comment: Just to clarify this answer, `fontname` should be of type `UIFont` and not just the name of the font as a string.

Comment: yes, for example let font = UIFont(name: "Lato-Light.ttf", size: 34). @DavidWilliames

Comment: Exactly :) although it would be "Lato-Light" not "Lato-Light.tff" :P

Comment: Also note that this answer affects all nav bars, not just this one specific nav bar.

Comment: I got this error. Cannot assign value of type 'UIFont?'
        to type [String: Any]? in swift 3.

Comment: So you need it in swift 3?

Comment: Yes bro. @KAR . I want it in swift 3

Comment: Have you tried this, self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "CaviarDreams", size: 20)!] ?

Comment: @MayPhyu you welcome. If its helpfull to you than upvote the answer and comment

Comment: bro @KAR, I don't want to add that code in each view controller. I would like   to add in one place and effect in every view controller. How to do this bro?

Comment: @DavidWilliames bro, could you help me please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44304498/how-to-set-font-family-to-uiviewcontroller-title-in-swift ?

Comment: **Swift 4.2** 
`self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "CaviarDreams", size: 20)!]`

Comment: The Objective-C and Swift code in this answer is not equivalent.  The Objective-C line changes the UINavigationBar via the appearance proxy which changes every navigation bar in the app.  The Swift versions set only a single navigation bar.

Answer (score 57):

Proper way how to set the font for every view controller in Swift (using Appearance proxy):

### Swift 5 (and 4.2)

```
let attributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 17)!]
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = attributes
```

### Swift 4

```
let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 17)!]
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = attributes
```

### Swift 3

```
let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 17)!]
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = attributes
```

Comment: For iOS 13 & above, use `UINavigationBarAppearance()`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61712504/4439983

Comment: None of them work if your navigationBar is set to `prefersLargeTitles = true`. if you have that set and you want to change the title font style, use `navigationController?.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.font: UIFont(name: "CustomFont"), size: 20), .foregroundColor: UIColor.black]`

Answer (score 20):

You can do this in Storyboard as well, there is a bug in Xcode 10.1 of doing this here is a trick to overcome this as well.

**Step 1 - Choose *System* from Font**

[image]

**Step 2 - Then again choose *Custom* and it will show all the fonts.**

[image]

Comment: This workaround worked (or is required) even in in `Xcode 10.2.1`. Thanks 

Comment: It takes effect in the interface builder but the navigation bar does not show the font change when run in simulator.

Answer (score 17):

**SWIFT 4.x**

To Change the Navigation bar title font for both Normal & **Large Title above iOS 11.x**

```
let navigation = UINavigationBar.appearance()

let navigationFont = UIFont(name: "Custom_Font_Name", size: 20)
let navigationLargeFont = UIFont(name: "Custom_Font_Name", size: 34) //34 is Large Title size by default

navigation.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, NSAttributedStringKey.font: navigationFont!]

if #available(iOS 11, *){
    navigation.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white, NSAttributedStringKey.font: navigationLargeFont!]
}
```

Large Title has to be set true in Navigation bar.

Answer (score 7):

## Swift 5

**I will show you how we do it in our company projects.**

1. We create a `UINavigationController` subclass.
2. Write our customization code in `viewDidLoad`.
3. Make every navigation controller in our storyboard files inherit
   from it.

That is very good for more than one reason. one of the reasons is the center point of change. Once we change something in the class, all navigation controllers listen to it.

**That's how our `UINavigationController` subclass looks.**

**COPY PASTE from work project.**

```
import UIKit

class NavigationController: UINavigationController
{
    // MARK: Navigation Controller Life Cycle

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       setFont()
    }

    // MARK: Methods

    func setFont()
    {
       // set font for title
       self.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Al-Jazeera-Arabic", size: 20)!]
    
       // set font for navigation bar buttons
       UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Al-Jazeera-Arabic", size: 15)!], for: UIControl.State.normal)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Swift 5 Easy way

```
//Programatically
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 40)!]
```

Physically

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

## Swift 5

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(descriptor: UIFontDescriptor(name: "American Typewriter Bold", size: 36), size: 36)]
```

Answer (score 1):

To call titleTextAttributes on the reference to the navigation bar use:

```
let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 17)!]
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = attributes
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Lato-Semibold", size: 17)!,NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.white]
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2 Xcode 10**

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Sacramento-Regular", size: 19)!]
```

Answer (score -1):

Be carefull, if you use custom font don't write

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "SF-Pro-Display-Medium", size: 18)!], for: UIControl.State.normal)
```

use font name without sumbol "-"

like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "SF Pro Display Medium", size: 18)!], for: UIControl.State.normal)
```