# How to set font family to Navigation Controller Title in swift?

Tags: uiviewcontroller, swift3, font-face, nslocalizedstring, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have one View Controller named "Home". I embed it in Navigation Controller.

```
 self.navBar.topItem?.title = "Home"
```

I would like to change "Tharlon" font to my UIViewController title bar.

```
self.navBar.topItem?.title = NSLocalizedString("Home", comment: "")
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Tharlon", size: 17)!]
```

Both these codes are in **ViewDidLoad()** function. 
 When I run the app, Translated text shows well at the first time. Then, I open other menus and goes back to Home. At that second time, translated text does not show well and it does not looks in Unicode font.  
[image]
That works well at the first time !

[image]

This is not well after I view other pages and goes back to Home.

I also tried to put these above code in **ViewWillAppear** . But it still not works. 
Please, can anyone help me?

Comment: Add **self.title = "Your title"** in your *viewDidLoad()*

Comment: @Anas, Translation works one time. It does not works in second time viewing the page.

Comment: In what method are you implementing this code? e.g. `viewDidLoad()`, `viewDidAppear()` etc.

Comment: Can you share more of your ViewController code?

Comment: did you try `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: Yes, I tried in ViewDidAppear. But now work. @Honey

Comment: @MayPhyu write this word in Burmese so that we can test it

Comment: @drOX, u mean this word ပင်မစာမျက်နှာ ? bro